# Excel formula to add and subtract percentage to the product cost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write an excel formula that if the **Product Price is >$10 then add 20 % to Price (Section 1), if the Price is >$11 then add 30% to the price (Section 2), if the price is >$50 then add 40% to the price (Section 3)**.

I wrote the below formula, but it is not working

`=IF(I4>0,I4+(I4*0.2),IF(I4>10,I4+(I4*0.3),I4+(I4*0.4)))`

Also, for **Section 1 it is needed to provide 30 % off on the Product price** and keep the new price in a new column,

**For Section 2 : 40 % off**

**For Section 3 : 50 % off**

This can be kept separated from the above.

Answer (score 3):

If resolves serially and will stop the first time it is `TRUE`.  So since the firs conditional is `I4>0` and all the other conditionals are also `>` it will never get past the first TRUE to even test the other items.

Reverse it:

```
=IF(I4>50,I4*(1+0.4),IF(I4>11,....
```

But we can do something shorter:

```
=I4*(1+(CHOOSE(MATCH(I4,{0,10,11,50}),0,.2,.3,.4))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked smoothly. The reversal helped me up

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the greatest limit inside `if`, as any number greater than 50 is greater than 40 too.

```
=IF(I4>50,I4*1.4,IF(I4>11,I4*1.3,IF(I4>10,I4*1.2,I4)))
```

For the second part, do the same

```
=IF(I4>50,I4*0.5,IF(I4>11,I4*0.6,IF(I4>10,I4*0.7,I4)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked smoothly. The reversal helped me up